# how to display 4 buttons in a jsp page with restrictive access?

Tags: java, struts

I want to display 4 buttons in a JSp page(BOMDisplay.jsp) in a restrictive manner.

Means, there is another page(RoleTransaction page) where we have to select the category(dropdown) and role(dropdown) and there are various checkboxes
that are meant to be selected for a particular role. These checkbox values are taken from the database. When we select the category and role and select the checkboxes for that particular role and click on the "save" button, the 4 buttons should be displayed in the JSp page(BOMDisplay.jsp) in a restrictive manner(based on the checkboxes selected for that particular role). The four buttons are suppose:-

1. button1
2. button2
3. button3
4. button4

These four buttons were newly inserted in the database as to be available for a particular role to select any combination of these buttons.

After clicking on the save button, the control goes to TransactionAction then to TransationBO and then to TransactionDAO. I have to implement the concept for the buttons to be available in BOMDisplay.jsp in a restrictive manner like i mentiones earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In spring,we use spring security feature sec:authorize. 
In struts, you can attach a role and display what is needed for that role.

@struts.action path="/customer" roles="viewer, editor"

Specify role in struts-config.xml

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am new to this application,please provide me with the code if you have it.